# How to lengthen the height of the text box above a frame in the presentation?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, framed

I am using beamer for making presentation in latex. I have come across an issue. In presentation, we have a box above the frame which outlines all the sections. However, in my case that box does not extend to accommodate the length of all the sections in the presentation (see attached figure, I have drawn a red box around the issue

[image]

Can anybody tell me the way to extend its length so that all sections are visible properly?

I am using following configuration

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beamer uses different lineskip-related settings when calculating the fixed height of headline and actually constructing the headline contents. Therefore, for large n, where n is the number of sections or subsections whichever is larger, actual total height of headline will be larger than the pre-cauculated fixed total height. This results in an `overfull \vbox` badbox report in log and the partially clipped last line of headline in pdf.

I have reported this (possible) problem to beamer, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/595. For a workaround, try adding the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\pretocmd\dohead
  {\offinterlineskip}
  {}{\fail}
```